# Magento installation stuck on 53%

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to install magento 2.1.3 but the installation stops at 53% at:

> Module 'Magento_Catalog':
>   Installing data...

With the error in console:

> POST http://local.magento/setup/index.php/install/start 500 (Internal Server Error)

And my magento/var/log/debug.log file showing:

> [2017-01-07 11:07:38] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://local.magento/setup/index.php/install/start","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []

My memory and execution time is set to:

```
memory_limit = 2048M
max_execution_time = 18000
```

Comment: Did you restart the web service after changing memory and execution time?

Comment: execution time was set by default to 18000, but after I changed memory limit from 64 to 2048 I did restarted the server.

Comment: You tried again with the same issue?

Comment: Yesssssssssssss